# Zooming Android Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, imageview, android-canvas, zooming

So I have a school project and I am making an Android application that acts as a keyboard for a computer. I know how to connect the application to the computer, but I am having difficultly developing a zooming feature for the keyboard (so the keys on the keyboard appear larger so a person with poor eyesight can see the keyboard more easily). If you could help me decide what view to use (such as imageview or canvas) and how to implement this idea into an application (buttons or images for keys). I know this sounds confusing but please ask questions and I will try to clarify.

**What the app needs to do:**

Zoom into a keyboard on screen

Detect which key is pressed (ex. button press or coordinates of touch location)

Thank you for your time and I hope you can help me :D

I actually was able to solve this my self with a little help from other posts on stackoverflow :D You can check it out here:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4wNh71RsR0 skip to like halfway through where the actual app is

Answer (score -1):

I'm just tying up loose ends here. So I finished this project a while back and I just wanted to link people, if they may be so inclined, to my project on GitHub: https://github.com/chrislegolife/KeyboardZoom. Use the code however you want, but don't expect it to live up to proper coding techniques as I was just beginning to learn socket programming when I built this.